# `firebase login` asks for sudo password

Tags: bash, firebase, permissions

Why does running `firebase login --no-localhost` in bash cause a prompt for sudo password to appear? Here's the output when I run the command:

```
? Allow Firebase to collect anonymous CLI usage information? No

Visit this URL on any device to log in: <auth_url_here>

? Paste authorization code here: [sudo] password for etl:
```

This is for a project at work on a production server so I don't have the password for etl user. When I installed Firebase, I followed the guides on npm's site to [fix permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) and then installed Firebase globally with:

```
npm install -g firebase firebase-tools
```

Comment: Firebase tries to open a browser using the [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) library when you login. It looks like that's what's triggering the sudo request. Maybe you could file an issue on that repo to see if there's a common solution?

Comment: I suppose that would be the best way to go. I get the sudo prompt whether the `--no-localhost` flag is set or not.